# How would i enable an unfocused window to still recieve event listeners?

Tags: windows, client-server, keyboard-shortcuts

I am working on a client-server application where the server will depending on buttons clicked, would fire all the events of a keyboard.  It is limited to the keyboard as well.

I am making a custom keyboard for my left hand.  A friend has only 1 hand so it similar would benefit him.  They keyboard will be some sort of touch device, possibly a large tablet, which will through networking and port connections establish a connection with my server.

My server applcation (written in anything really, python, C, C++, java, I know a LOT of languages) will accept a flag, and then execute a set of commands.

Essentially i want to do something like:

```
if(key_pressed == 'f1')
  execute the 'F1' key in focused window.
```

Server application is NOT focused and will be hidden, or minimized on screen.

Is there a way to go that without building custom drivers or something?

**Edit:**

Client is like having a keyboard
Server is like the driver.   I want the server to fire off things as if it is a character device being manipulated.  The thing i was looking into is that i was reading a post or 2 which said only focused applications receive presses, which is fine, i want them to execute in the focused window, but in the background, be a process which will catch and then carry out the signal wanted like in the key_pressed above

Comment: Apologies but I don't understand exactly what you are asking for? As for implementation I would be tempted to use an RPC (remote procedure call) solution, where each key press triggers the necessary response on the sever. For reference I'm the developer of a network library that provides this functionality, http://www.networkcomms.net.

Comment: Let me make a quick edit.

Comment: Emulating the key strokes is not a problem, just use SendInput().  This otherwise completely depends on your ability to interface with the touch device.  Nothing sane can be said about that when you don't specify one.

Comment: Which Language uses SendInput in such a fashion.  I want to assume that i can interface with a device securely.  I just need to figure out what sort of application i should write to write for my windows machine which carries out the SendInput() command.